# Fragment holding a RecyclerView not showing in the MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to show a RecyclerView, in a fragment, in my main activity.
I'm not getting any errors, but the fragment remains empty, and I can't find the solution for this problem.
I simply have a fragment that has a recyclerview in it, I configure the recyclerview in HomeFragment.java, then in the MainParkActivity, I have a FrameLayout, which is replaced with the HomeFragment.

## MainParkActivity

```
package com.example.ipark;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;;

public class MainParkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "MainParkActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        Fragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("iParc");

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, homeFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

## HomeFragment

```
package com.example.ipark;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "HomeFragment";

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> mImageUrls = new ArrayList<>();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        RecyclerView recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

        giveInformation();

        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getContext(), mNames, mImageUrls);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void giveInformation() {
        mImageUrls.add("https://loremflickr.com/300/300/bmw");
        mNames.add("BMW");

        mImageUrls.add("https://loremflickr.com/300/300/bmw");
        mNames.add("Audi");

        mImageUrls.add("https://loremflickr.com/300/300/bmw");
        mNames.add("Hyundai");

        mImageUrls.add("https://loremflickr.com/300/300/bmw");
        mNames.add("Mercedes");

        mImageUrls.add("https://loremflickr.com/300/300/bmw");
        mNames.add("BMW");

        mImageUrls.add("https://loremflickr.com/300/300/bmw");
        mNames.add("Audi");

        mImageUrls.add("https://loremflickr.com/300/300/bmw");
        mNames.add("Hyundai");

        mImageUrls.add("https://loremflickr.com/300/300/bmw");
        mNames.add("Mercedes");
    }
}
```

## RecyclerViewAdapter

```
package com.example.ipark;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewAdapter";

    private ArrayList<String> mImageNames;
    private ArrayList<String> mImages;
    private Context mContext;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<String> mImageNames, ArrayList<String> mImages) {
        this.mImageNames = mImageNames;
        this.mImages = mImages;
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder;
        holder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: called.");

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(mImages.get(position))
                .into(holder.image);

        holder.imageName.setText(mImageNames.get(position));

        holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: clicked on: " + mImageNames.get(position));

                Toast.makeText(mContext, mImageNames.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mImageNames.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CircleImageView image;
        TextView imageName;
        RelativeLayout parentLayout;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
            imageName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_name);
            parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_layout);
        }
    }
}

}
```

## XML for activity_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainParkActivity"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar">

    </FrameLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

## XML for fragment_home

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Try changing the recycleview  viewholder holder name to some thing else. and also try to call set adapter inside the giveInformation() method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **fragment_home.xml**, your `Recyclerview` has `layout_height` and `layout_width` **0dp**. Change it to `match_parent`. Everything else in your code is correct. I'd have commented it, but I currently do not have commenting privileges! Accept it if you found it helpful!

Comment: I checked the layout in Android Studio myself, it didn't show recyclerview when height and width was 0dp. I changed it to match_parent and it started showing recyclerview.

Comment: Ok, it works, but what is that white border at the bottom? https://imgur.com/a/GVcBWb1

Comment: In your `fragment_home`, you've set `android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"`, remove that and it'll be gone. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped you!

Comment: @VedprakashWagh That may be so, but using `match_parent` is not recommended when using `constraint_layout`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout#widgets-dimension-constraints

The correct answer here would be to set the constraints properly, as I said in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your `activity_main` layout, you have `app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"`

It should be `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"`

Your layout is currently displaying above the screen in your fragment.

Answer (score -1):

use

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

after setting the adapter for RecycleView.

Comment: You only have to call this if you're changing the data after you've set the adapter on the `RecyclerView`.